# Why Goose Postgres Failed to Migrate SQL Command?

Tags: postgresql, go, goose

In `003_feeds.sql` file, the feeds table looks like this:

```sql
-- +goose Up
CREATE TABLE feeds (
  id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  url TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  user_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- +goose Down
DROP TABLE feeds;
```

This table has been tested with endpoints and it worked just fine.

In my `005_feed_lastfetched.sql`file, I want to alter the `feeds` table by specifying the following SQL query:

```sql
-- +goose UP
ALTER TABLE feeds ADD COLUMN last_fetched_at TIMESTAMP;
```

In the terminal, I run:

```bash
goose postgres postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/blog-aggregator up
```

The error message:

```bash
goose run: ERROR 005_feed_lastfetched.sql: failed to parse SQL migration file: failed to parse migration: unexpected state 0 on line "ALTER TABLE feeds ADD COLUMN last_fetched_at TIMESTAMP;", see https://github.com/pressly/goose#sql-migrations
```

It is worth noting that my 001 - 004 files SQL queries worked just fine, and I could successfully insert the above column in pgAdmin's query tool. And it is a Go project.

I searched online and could not find useful infos. Can anyone help enlighten a bit on this?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why no add the field during the creation process (in step 03) ?

Comment: I am building the project step by step, so that I could keep track of the process I worked. Thanks.

Comment: Problem fixed: I accidentally wrote Up to UP, and this caused the problem.